# how to use ScreenToClient in win32, not MFC?

Tags: winapi

As MSDN said

```
BOOL ScreenToClient(
  _In_  HWND hWnd,
  LPPOINT lpPoint
);
```

the ScreenToClient's second para is a pointer to POINT, 
and PINT said by MSDN is

```
typedef struct tagPOINT {
  LONG x;
  LONG y;
} POINT, *PPOINT;
```

it has only x and y. It's NOT like MFC ScreenToClient function, the para is a rect, and rect has width and height.
I am confused how to use win32 ScreenToClient function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MFC actually has two methods, they're overloaded. One accepts a `POINT` structure, just like the Win32 function, the other accepts a `RECT` structure, both work the same way: it maps each point from screen-to-client.

If you have a `RECT` that you want to get client coordinates of without using MFC then just do it manually, like so:

```
RECT rect = GetMyRect();

POINT rectTL;
rectTL.x = rect.left;
rectTL.y = rect.top;
ScreenToClient( hWnd, &rectTL );

POINT rectBR;
rectBR.x = rect.right
rectBR.y = rect.bottom;
ScreenToClient( hWnd, &rectBR );

rect.left   = rectTL.x;
rect.top    = rectTL.y;
rect.right  = rectBR.x;
rect.bottom = rectBR.y;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`MapWindowPoints()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046.aspx) to convert a RECT in a single operation:

```
RECT r = ...;
MapWindowPoints(NULL, hWnd, (LPPOINT)&r, 2);
```

Comment: +1 - using a RECT here might look odd, but it's specifically supported and doc'd on MSDN, in case anyone's wondering about it making assumptions: and it also does the right thing in Right-to-left mirroring situations, which ClientToScreen doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `RECT` is

```
typedef struct _RECT {
  LONG left;
  LONG top;
  LONG right;
  LONG bottom;
} RECT, *PRECT;
```

and looks like two consecutive POINTs in memory. Therefore you can do what the MFC source code does, which is approx. the following (don't have the MFC source in front of me right now):

```
::ScreenToClient(hWnd, (POINT*)&rect->left);
::ScreenToClient(hWnd, (POINT*)&rect->right);
```

which is not the cleanest thing from a C point of view, but those structures are bound to remain binary compatible.

Comment: It works, but I never like making assumptions about structure in-memory layout.

Comment: Sure, but as every MFC application does this, backwards compatibility will require Microsoft to never change that memory layout. But go ahead and copy the members to two POINT structures and back again if you wish.

Comment: From the point of view of the next programmer to come along and read the code, the underlying assumptions--correct or not--are not obvious.  It just looks like a dubious cast.  A trick like this may be necessary for performance, but until you have data to support that, it's a premature optimization.